# Calculating row and column totals form csv files

Tags: python, csv, python-3.8

I have the following CSV file about family expenses:

```
Family, Medical, Travel, Education
Smith, 346, 566, 45
Taylor, 56,837,848
```

I want to be able to calculate the row totals and column totals. For example:

```
Smith = 346+566+45
Taylor = 56+837+848
Medical = 346+56
Travel = 566+837
Education = 45+848
```

I have the following so far:

```
import csv
file = open('Family expenses.csv', newline='')
reader = csv.reader(file)

header = next(reader)
data = [row for row in header]
ndata = []
x = 0
for x in range(0, 3):
    for i in data[x]:
        i.split(',')
        x += 1
        ndata.append(i)

rdata = [int(s) if s.isdecimal() else s for s in ndata]
```

Comment: This seems like a good use case for the [pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-read-csv-table)

Comment: Yeah. is there any way to do it without the pandas library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for pandas for this; using DictReader makes it easy:

```
import csv

file = open("Family expenses.csv", newline="")
reader = csv.DictReader(file, skipinitialspace=True)

results = {}
for row in reader:
    results[row["Family"]] = 0  # initialize result for each family name
    for key, value in row.items():
        if key == "Family":
            continue
        if key not in results:  # initialize result for each category
            results[key] = 0
        results[key] += float(value)  # add value for category
        results[row["Family"]] += float(value)  # add value for family name

for key, result in results.items():
    print(key, result)
```

I used `skipinitialspace` because there were some whitespaces in your CSV data.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!. Can you explain to me how this code works again?

Comment: For every row in the CSV file (except for the `header` which is processed by the `DictReader` automatically) it initializes the sum for each family name and then goes over every `key:value` pair in that row and adds the value to the appropriate key in the `results` dict. The `Family` column is not added because it contains the family name, not an actual amount (that's what the continue `statement` is for).

Answer (score 0):

```py
#Using a list in Python. Here you go

import csv
file = open('Family expenses.csv', newline='')
reader = csv.reader(file)
header = next(reader) #read first row & skip first row (header)
header.pop(0) #removing [0,0] first row first column for column wise sum heading
num_of_cols = len(header) #counting #columns
sum_col=[0,0,0] #a list for columnwise sum
j,temp=0,0
for row in reader:
    sum_row,i = 0,0
    print(row[0])
    for i in range(1,len(row)):
        sum_row+=int(row[i])
        sum_col[i-1]=int(sum_col[i-1])+int(row[i])
    print(sum_row)
print(header)
print(sum_col)`
```